# PYTHON - Delete documents in partition collection in cosmos db

Tags: python-3.x, azure-cosmosdb

I am new in python scripting and currently developing a piece of code to delete documents in cosmos db .

The script successfully deletes the document in non-partition collection. 
When i use the same for partition collection i get 400 error and when i use partition key in options i get 404 resource not found.

1) i use query documents to select the records and write in file as backup

2) taking -self and put it in list

3) iterates the _self and delete using below code which is not working in partition collections

```
#options['partitionkey']='Ne2214553' 
#options['partitionkey']='/name' 

for i in lstlength:
                                item=lst[i]
                                print('item:',item)
                                del_itm_cnt=del_itm_cnt+1
                                client.DeleteDocument(item,options)
```

what should i have to pass in options, i tried with name of partition key ('/name') and value for partition key ('Ne2214553')

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set value of partition key like `'Ne2214553'` not `'/name'`.

```
options = {}
options['partitionKey'] = 'Ne2214553'
client.DeleteDocument("dbs/db/colls/part/docs/1", options)
```

Above code works for me , you could check the value of `item` in you code if matches with the value of partition key you provided.